# Simple csv being correupted when imported as Google Earth Engine asset

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a CSV of ~500 lat/long locations that I import into my assets as a Table. When I import that Table into my GEE script as a FeatureCollection, the lat/long values get distorted a bit after 5 decimal places. Why is that happening and how do I avoid that?

i.e. the csv contains the lat/long location [7.908736706, 37.2028923] and the imported GEE table contains [7.90873743310952, 37.20289098574329]. Close but no cigar! What's going on here?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question so that it focuses on one issue.

Comment: It looks like it's being converted into a floating point, or the values you have in your csv have been rounded (this is probably the case if you're viewing the csv in excel). When you view the csv in a text editor, do the values match up with GEE?